# TNetHTTPClient clear cookies

Tags: http, delphi, cookies, firemonkey

I am using a TNetHTTPClient in a Delphi 10.2.3 Firemonkey project and would like to clear all stored cookies. I did not find any solution in the help files. I tried this code, but I get the error that the array is read-only:

```
SetLength(NetHTTPClient1.CookieManager.Cookies, 0);
```

What can I do to clear all cookies, without destroying the instance of TNetHTTPClient and creating it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, many thanks to BigBother and Toon Krijthe in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351215/how-to-access-a-private-field-from-a-class-helper-in-delphi-10-1-berlin) about class helpers!

As `CookieManager.Cookies` is read-only, I tried to gain access to the private field `TCookies` via a class helper, which does not work anymore since 10.1 Berlin. However, Toon Krijthe found a way, and I adapted it to suit my needs:

Interface:

```
type
  TCookieManagerHelper = class helper for TCookieManager
    procedure DeleteCookies;
  end;
```

Implementation:

```
procedure TCookieManagerHelper.DeleteCookies;
begin
  with self do
    FCookies.clear;
end;
```

Whenever I want to clear cookies:

```
NetHTTPClient1.CookieManager.DeleteCookies;
```

I have to add that this might not work with future versions of Delphi, as Embarcadero disabled accessing private fields via class helpers on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea:

```
for i := 0 to High(NetHTTPClient1.CookieManager.Cookies)
  do NetHTTPClient1.CookieManager.Cookies[i].Expires := Now - 1;

NetHTTPClient1.CookieManager.dCookies;
```

This way you can set all cookies as expired.
Getting cookies again call `GetCookies` that internally call `DeleteExpiredCookies`

**Edit**

**Unfortunetely this will not work (read comments below for details)**

Comment: I really like your idea. Unfortunately, the property "Cookies" is read-only: property Cookies: TCookiesArray read GetCookies;

Comment: Hi @Flo it doesn't matter, expired cookies are cleared on property read!

Comment: Hi BigBother, your statement is absolutely correct. But as the whole array of cookies is read-only, I cannot modify the `Expires` property. Does your code work for you?

Comment: Hi @Flo, the `Cookies` array is readonly (you cannot assign to it) but its elements (`TCookie` records) are not, you can modify single cookie property `Expires` without any problem (I'm under Delphi 10.2.2, not updated to 10.2.3 yet)

Comment: I just tried it again, I cannot change any value of the record. They preserve their original value.

Comment: @Flo totally my bad, GetCookies returns an array derived from FCookies (which is a TList instead) so you can modify a single cookie, but your edits will be lost...

Comment: BigBother, never mind. Your idea was helpful, anyway.