# How to access the private method TStreamReader.FillBuffer in Delphi 10.1 Berlin?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, class-helpers

How to access the private method TStreamReader.FillBuffer in Delphi 10.1 Berlin, we did it with a class helper before 10.1 - but the proposed solution does not work:

```
uses System.Rtti;
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Assert(Assigned(TRttiContext.Create.GetType(TStreamReader).GetMethod('FillBuffer')), 
    'Failed');
end;
```

it fails just because GetMethod returns NIL. Any ideas why this fails?

Edited:
**I do want to know WHY it fails**

Comment: It probably fails because it was not compiled with extended RTTI enabled.

Comment: Have you seen @LURD's answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716363/how-to-access-private-methods-without-helpers/37761852#37761852

Comment: @Rudy: I've tried adding {$METHODINFO ON} in my unit1.pas but I think this should be done in system.classes (where TStreamReader is declared).

Comment: @MartynA: `TMethod(P).Code := @TStreamReader.FillBuffer` does work, thank you please add as an answer

Comment: Glad it worked, but I think it would be better if you add your own answer, as I don't know what code you ended up using exactly.

Comment: We don't need to keep replicating answers to the same question @MartynA, closing as a duplicate is the correct thing to do

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Fine, but I'm not convinced it is a duplicate.  The OP asks " GetMethod returns NIL. Any ideas why this fails?" which the other q doesn't address nor answer, afaics.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The private fields are visible with GetFields, but the private methods not. There is no $METHODINFO ON for this class which would be the answer to the question I think.... therefore it is not a duplicate question

Comment: See also [RTTI access to private methods of VCL, e.g. TCustomForm.SetWindowState](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37905306/576719).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because the private methods aren't included in this class.
See [RTTI access to private methods of VCL, e.g. TCustomForm.SetWindowState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905306/rtti-access-to-private-methods-of-vcl-e-g-tcustomform-setwindowstate)

There is a workaround for getting the private method though:

See: [How to access private methods without helpers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716363/how-to-access-private-methods-without-helpers/37761852#37761852)

```
type
  TStreamReaderHelper = class helper for TStreamReader
  public
    procedure FillBuffer(var Encoding: TEncoding);
  end;

procedure TStreamReaderHelper.FillBuffer(var Encoding: TEncoding);
var
  Method: procedure(var Encoding: TEncoding) of object;
begin
  TMethod(Method).Code := @TStreamReader.FillBuffer;
  TMethod(Method).Data := Self;
  Method(Encoding);
end;
```