# Delphi XE 10.1 JVCL Installation Failed

Tags: delphi, jvcl

I have installed the latest JCL 2016-10-10
and I want to install the latest JVCL, but I'm getting some error messages.

How I can install it?

> Windows 10 Home  (10.0.0)
>
> JVCL 3.50.0.0
>
> [Generating: Packages]
>
> Generating packages for D24
>
> Loaded template.dpk
>
> Loaded template.dproj
>
> Loaded template.rc
>
> [Compiling: Packages]
>
> [Compiling: JvCore240.bpl]
>
> Embarcadero Delphi for Win32 compiler version 31.0
>
> Copyright (c) 1983,2016 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
>
> E:\DelphiComp\XE10.1\JVCL3-2016-10-10\run\JvAppIniStorage.pas(261) Error: E2361 Cannot access private symbol TMemIniFile.FSections
>
> E:\DelphiComp\XE10.1\JVCL3-2016-10-10\run\JvAppIniStorage.pas(261) Warning: W1023 Comparing signed and unsigned types - widened both operands
>
> E:\DelphiComp\XE10.1\JVCL3-2016-10-10\run\JvAppIniStorage.pas(261) Error: E2014 Statement expected, but expression of type 'Boolean' found
>
> E:\DelphiComp\XE10.1\JVCL3-2016-10-10\run\JvAppIniStorage.pas(274) Error: E2361 Cannot access private symbol TMemIniFile.FSections
>
> JvCore.dpk(2356) Fatal: F2063 Could not compile used unit 'JvAppIniStorage.pas'

Comment: You say that you are trying to install the latest, but you aren't. This issue was fixed back in April. This is such a common mistake. Make sure you know how to use VCS and get the latest.

Answer (score 1):

The Delphi 10.1 Berlin version removed the access of private members through class helpers (see [How to access private methods without helpers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36716363/576719)). That is the error message you can see, when access to `TMemIniFile.FSections` is denied.

Looking at the latest code for [JvAppIniStorage.pas](https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl/blob/master/jvcl/run/JvAppIniStorage.pas), this is fixed:

```
{ Optimization of TCustomIniFile.ValueExists.
  Note that this is a dirty hack, a better way would be to rewrite TMemIniFile;
  especially expose FSections. }
{$IFDEF DELPHI2009_UP}
type
  TMemIniFileAccess = class(TCustomIniFile)
  {$IFDEF RTL310_UP} // 10.1 Berlin removed the access to private fields
    {$IFDEF RTL320_UP}
      {$MESSAGE WARN 'Check that the new RTL still has FSections as the first member of TMemIniFile'}
    {$ENDIF RTL320_UP}
  private
    FSections: TStringList;
  {$ENDIF RTL310_UP}
  end;
```

As said in code comments, this is a dirty hack that works if the `FSections` still is declared as the first field in `TCustomIniFile`.

And in code:

```
function TMemIniFileHelper.SectionExists(const Section: string): Boolean;
begin
  {$IFDEF RTL310_UP} // 10.1 Berlin removed the access to private fields
  Result := TMemIniFileAccess(Self).FSections.IndexOf(Section) >= 0;
  {$ELSE}
  Result := Self.FSections.IndexOf(Section) >= 0;
  {$ENDIF RTL310_UP}
end;
```

Make sure you have the latest source for jvcl and recompile. Note that the symbol `RTL310_UP` is defined in [jedi.inc](https://github.com/project-jedi/jedi/blob/master/jedi.inc).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, from an oop point of view perhaps, but a pragmatic programmer use whatever option there is.

Comment: Hi David,Thank you for your comments. But I can't do it.

Comment: I have downloaded latest sources via SourceTree. I have installed jcl successfully. But jvcl has same error message.

Comment: Did you confirm that `jedi.inc` includes the `RTL310_UP` definition?

Comment: @OsmanTaşkıran, it is clear to me that your `JvAppIniStorage.pas` is the updated version, but also that your `jedi.inc` is wrong. If you look at the compiler error line numbers (Line 261), they match the path of the `{$ELSE}` directive in the `SectionExists()` snippet above. If the `inc` file contained the correct definition, the compiler would have compiled line 259 (`Result := TMemIniFileAccess(Self).FSections.IndexOf(Section) >= 0;`) instead.