# Token Based Authentication using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, oauth, netsuite

We currently have an access database and are attempting to connect to an API using TBA. The code below is what we have so far. We can connect using just username and password but can not get the TBA code to work. Any help is much appreciated. I've already double checked the strings.

```
'working code
'reader.Open "GET", "NetSuite API URL, False
'reader.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "NLAuth nlauth_account=****,nlauth_email=***, nlauth_signature=****, nlauth_role=***"


reader.Open "GET", "NetSuite API URL", False

Dim RealmStr As String
Dim ConsumKeyStr As String
Dim ConsumSecStr As String
Dim TokenStr As String

RealmStr = "..."
ConsumKeyStr = "..."
ConsumSecStr = "..."
TokenStr = "..."
TokenSecStr = "..."


Application.Run "CreateHeader", RealmStr, ConsumKeyStr, ConsumSecStr, TokenStr, TokenSecStr
XMLReqStr = Chr$(34) & XMLReqStr & Chr$(34)

reader.setRequestHeader "Authorization", XMLReqStr

reader.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
reader.Send


Do Until reader.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Here is the create header function.

```
Public Function CreateHeader(Realm As String, ConsumerKey As String, ConsumerSecret As String, Token As String, TokenSecret As String) As String
    Dim auth_Nonce As String
    Dim auth_Timestamp As String
    Dim auth_Base As String
    Dim auth_SigningKey As String
    Dim auth_Signature As String
    
    ' create nonce and timestamp
    auth_Nonce = CreateNonce()
    auth_Timestamp = VBA.CStr(VBA.DateDiff("s", #1/1/1970#, ConvertToUtc(VBA.Now)))
    
    ' Create needed parts of authorization header
    auth_Base = CreateBaseString(auth_Nonce, auth_Timestamp, ConsumerKey, Token)
    auth_SigningKey = ConsumerSecret & "&" & TokenSecret
    auth_Signature = HMACSHA256(auth_Base, auth_SigningKey, "Base64")
    
    XMLSignStr = auth_SigningKey
    
    ' Generate header
    CreateHeader = "OAuth "
    
    ' Add realm (if exists)
    'If Realm <> "" Then
    '    CreateHeader = CreateHeader & "realm=" & Realm & ", "
    'End If
    
    If Realm <> "" Then
        CreateHeader = CreateHeader & "realm=" & Chr$(34) & Realm & Chr$(34) & ","
    End If
    
      
     CreateHeader = CreateHeader & "oauth_consumer_key=""" & ConsumerKey & ""","
     CreateHeader = CreateHeader & "oauth_token=""" & Token & ""","
     CreateHeader = CreateHeader & "oauth_signature_method=""HMAC-SHA256"","
     CreateHeader = CreateHeader & "oauth_timestamp=""" & auth_Timestamp & ""","
     CreateHeader = CreateHeader & "oauth_nonce=""" & auth_Nonce & ""","
     CreateHeader = CreateHeader & "oauth_version=""" & "1.0" & ""","
     CreateHeader = CreateHeader & "oauth_signature=""" & UrlEncode(auth_Signature) & """"
   
    
    
    CreateHeader = CreateHeader
    XMLReqStr = CreateHeader
    XMLSignStr = UrlEncode(auth_Signature)
    
End Function
```

Comment: The problem is probably in your XMLReqStr. Can you post your CreateHeader sub?

Comment: Also, what error are you getting?

Comment: I posted the CreateHeader.

Comment: You need to sign more of the request, here is an example in another language but shows what needs to be signed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957730/delphi-toauth1authenticator-how-to-set-the-realm

Comment: Looks like we may be missing the Script_ID and Script_deployment_ID?