# Delphi OAuth 1.0a “one-legged” Authentication

Tags: rest, delphi, oauth

I would like to know if anyone knows how to make this type of request in delphi, I already looked a lot on the internet for how to do it and I can't find anything, the native components of the shipper don't work with this type of request!

Someone to help !!!!!!

```
OAuth1Authenticator1.ConsumerKey := ConsumerKey;
OAuth1Authenticator1.ConsumerSecret := ConsumerSecret;
OAuth1Authenticator1.SigningClassName := 'TOAuth1SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1';
RESTClient1.Authenticator := OAuth1Authenticator1;
RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'http://myUrl/wp-json/wc/v3';
RESTRequest1.Resource := 'orders';
RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;
RESTRequest1.Execute;

if assigned(RESTResponse1.JSONValue) then
 begin
   Memo1.Lines.Text := TJson.Format(RESTResponse1.JSONValue)
 end
 else
 begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(RESTResponse1.Content);
  end;
```

Comment: The answer to this question does it for NetSuite: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957730/delphi-toauth1authenticator-how-to-set-the-realm

Comment: Please tell us what you tried to do so far (with some code) and show us where you’re stuck (do you get an error?)

Comment: @R.Hoek added the source code!

Comment: @Brian in this case it doesn't work, as I'm trying to use the one-legged OAuth 1.0 Authentication.

Comment: Are your getting an error? If so, what error. Also provide some feedback about this this authentication (some links to the specifications would be nice), what are the specs for it and in which context are you using it.

Comment: Have you tried first with Postman, for example? Could you post the results please?