# Netsuite Works in POSTMAN but not in cUrl - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, curl, oauth, postman, netsuite

I'm trying to create a new customer to NetSuite using a RESTlet. I get a successful add in Postman, but when I try in PHP - cURL code from Postman to replicate in my code, I get the following:

I'm generating the Oauth 1.0, and it works fine in a order record, just in customer that it doesn't.

```php
    $base_string =
        "POST&" . urlencode(NETSUITE_URL) . "&" .
        urlencode(
             "&oauth_consumer_key=" . NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY
            . "&oauth_nonce=" . $oauth_nonce
            . "&oauth_signature_method=" . $oauth_signature_method
            . "&oauth_timestamp=" . $oauth_timestamp
            . "&oauth_token=" . NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID
            . "&oauth_version=" . $oauth_version
            . "&realm=" . NETSUITE_ACCOUNT

        );
    $sig_string = urlencode(NETSUITE_CONSUMER_SECRET) . '&' . urlencode(NETSUITE_TOKEN_SECRET);
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $base_string, $sig_string, true));

    $auth_header = "OAuth "
        . 'oauth_signature="' . rawurlencode($signature) . '", '
        . 'oauth_version="' . rawurlencode($oauth_version) . '", '
        . 'oauth_nonce="' . rawurlencode($oauth_nonce) . '", '
        . 'oauth_signature_method="' . rawurlencode($oauth_signature_method) . '", '
        . 'oauth_consumer_key="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY) . '", '
        . 'oauth_token="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID) . '", '
        . 'oauth_timestamp="' . rawurlencode($oauth_timestamp) . '", '
        . 'realm="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_ACCOUNT) . '"';

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://8648945.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{
    "companyName": "Company 1615554322",
    "email": "customer@example.com"
}',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: ' . $auth_header . ''
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;`
```

The error I'm getting:

> "title": "Unauthorized",
> "status": 401,
> Invalid login attempt. For more details, see the Login Audit Trail in the NetSuite UI at Setup > Users/Roles > User Management >
> View Login Audit Trail

I'm using this code to add order, but when I try to record a customer, I got this error.

Comment: Realm should not be included in the text that is signed and the parameters also need to be sorted. See the documentation reference at the bottom of this question and the comments in the code of the answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957730/delphi-toauth1authenticator-how-to-set-the-realm