# InvalidSignature error while calling a restlet using TBA in Node JS

Tags: node.js, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to call a Restlet using TBA in Node JS. In response, a 403 response code is being returned and the error is InvalidSignature as per View Login Audit trail in Netsuite.

This means something is wrong with the way the Oauth signature is being created in the code but I am not able to figure out what it is because the same authorization code worked properly for NetSuite REST APIs. Kindly help in figuring out that. Here's the code :-

```
function upsertUsingRestlet(body, callbackFn) {

  const baseUrl = `https://${NETSUITE_ACCOUNT_ID}.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=${SCRIPT_ID}&deploy=${DEPLOYMENT_ID}`;
  const oauthSignatureMethod = 'HMAC-SHA256';
  const oauthVersion = '1.0';
  const oauthNonce = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
  const oauthTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

  const oauthParameters = {
    oauth_consumer_key: CONSUMER_KEY,
    oauth_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
    oauth_nonce: oauthNonce,
    oauth_timestamp: oauthTimestamp,
    oauth_signature_method: oauthSignatureMethod,
    oauth_version: '1.0'
  };

  const sortedParameters = Object.keys(oauthParameters)
    .sort()
    .map((key) => `${key}=${oauthParameters[key]}`)
    .join('&');

  const signatureBaseString = `POST&${encodeURIComponent(baseUrl)}&${encodeURIComponent(sortedParameters)}`;
  const signingKey = `${CONSUMER_SECRET}&${ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET}`;
  const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', signingKey);
  hmac.update(signatureBaseString);
  let oauthSignature = hmac.digest('base64');
  oauthSignature = encodeURIComponent(oauthSignature);

  const headers = {
    'Prefer': 'transient',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `OAuth realm="${REALM}",oauth_nonce="${oauthNonce}",oauth_signature_method="${oauthSignatureMethod}",oauth_consumer_key="${CONSUMER_KEY}",oauth_token="${ACCESS_TOKEN}",oauth_timestamp="${oauthTimestamp}",oauth_version="${oauthVersion}",oauth_signature="${oauthSignature}"`
  };

  fetch(baseUrl, {
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': headers,
    'body': body,
    'redirect': 'follow'
  })
    .then((response) => response)
    .then((data) => {
      callbackFn(data.status);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error upsertOperation:', error);
    });
}
```

Comment: A quick look: you need to include script and deploy in the sorted list of oauthParameters that you sign. Also remove those two parameters from the baseurl that you sign. Question with a working answer in another language you can compare with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957730/delphi-toauth1authenticator-how-to-set-the-realm

Comment: It worked, thanks! You can post it as an answer, I'll accept it.