# Generate OAuth1.0 Headers for NetSuite

Tags: php, oauth, netsuite

I need to write a PHP (8.2) function that calls a RESTlet on a NetSuite instance. To call this RESTlet, I'm using the Token-based Authentication (TBA) method, which in practice seems to be OAuth 1.0. All of the off-the-shelf libraries I've found for OAuth 1.0 in PHP do not use all parts of NetSuite's TBA, namely the consumer and token secrets, so I don't think they'll work. Of note, I'm not able to get the [oauth PHP extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/oauth/2.0.7/windows) working on my machine, presumably because it was released for PHP 7.4, so I'm generating the base string portion using method shown in SOAP Web Services section. **Update**: I've also tried using the `restletBaseString` function [as provided by NetSuite](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_1534939551.html#subsect_1520632716), but that did not work either.

As such, I'm trying to create the authorization header myself [following the guide created by NetSuite](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_1534941088.html#subsect_1520523321), but keep getting `INVALID LOGIN ATTEMPT`. This is despite putting my generated headers side-by-side headers created in Postman, and them seeming to be identical. Also potentially important, when I check the Login Audit trail for the account associated with these credentials, I see **no** failed login attempts.

**All sensitive information has been changed out, but my actual values have been directly copy/pasted from Postman where it's been working**

```php
<?php

define("ACCOUNT_ID", "1234567_SB1");
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "8daa8433f54386d63a5317d71fef801cf47a8cc3d9552be3d0f63fc8ab6de8f9");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "72ad5f9134091493a108a72f283733304e4218d37bc559ca99d5fd46742f7ca1");
define("TOKEN_KEY", "65d48649dcf0f8ad2da444af1d16377232bb4a5f8ffa8f3fb6175a3e6a8ed0e5");
define("TOKEN_SECRET", "bb07a68caf57fb6628661f10e687d065959cb7ab1ad6e19da1467718c67b7d6b");
define("COMPANY_URL", "https://1234567-sb1.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl");

$url = COMPANY_URL."?script=2211&deploy=1&id=28099";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "Authorization: ".createOAuthHeader("GET", $url),
    "Content-type: application/json",
    /* Only here to test if a lack of a user-agent was the cause. It was not */
    "User-Agent: Mozilla 5.0",
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$empty = curl_exec($ch);

/**
 * Create the OAuth header for NetSuite REST calls
 */
function createOAuthHeader(string $httpMethod = "GET", $url): string
{
    $authorizor = [
        "oauth_consumer_key" => CONSUMER_KEY,
        "oauth_token" => TOKEN_KEY,
        "oauth_signature_method" => "HMAC-SHA256",
        "oauth_timestamp" => time(),
        "oauth_nonce" => getOAuthNonce(),
        "oauth_version" => "1.0"
    ];

    // Create the Base String
    // Failed attempt
    // $base = join("&", array_map("rawurlencode", array_merge([$httpMethod, $url], flattenAssociativeArray($authorizor, false))));
    // $base = oauth_get_sbs($httpMethod, $url, $authorizor);
    // $base = join("&", [
    //     rawurlencode(ACCOUNT_ID),
    //     rawurlencode(CONSUMER_KEY),
    //     rawurlencode(TOKEN_KEY),
    //     rawurlencode($authorizor["oauth_nonce"]),
    //     rawurlencode($authorizor["oauth_timestamp"])
    // ]);
    // Also doesn't work
    $base = restletBaseString($httpMethod, $url, CONSUMER_KEY, TOKEN_KEY, getOAuthNonce(), time(), "1.0", "HMAC-SHA256", $postParams);

    // Create the HMAC signature key
    $key = rawurlencode(CONSUMER_SECRET)."&".rawurlencode(TOKEN_SECRET);

    // Add the base64-encoded signature to the authorizor array
    $authorizor["oauth_signature"] = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $base, $key, true));

    // URL encode the values in the authorizor ID
    $authorizorEncoded = array_map("rawurlencode", ["realm" => ACCOUNT_ID, ...$authorizor]);

    // Flattens the key/value pairs into an array of strings in the form of key="value"
    $final = flattenAssociativeArray($authorizorEncoded, true);

    return "OAuth ".join(",", $final);
}

function getOAuthNonce(): string
{
    return substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 11);
}

function flattenAssociativeArray(array $arr, bool $quoteValue = true): array
{
    $formatString = $quoteValue ? '%s="%s"' : "%s=%s";

    return array_map(
        fn($key, $value): string => sprintf($formatString, $key, $value)
        , array_keys($arr)
        , array_values($arr)
    );
}

/**
 * The function used to create the base string for the OAuth signature as provided by NetSuite
 * @see https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_1534939551.html#subsect_1520632716
 */
function restletBaseString($httpMethod, $url, $consumerKey, $tokenKey, $nonce, $timestamp, $version, $signatureMethod, $postParams){
    //http method must be upper case
    $baseString = strtoupper($httpMethod) .'&';
    
    //include url without parameters, schema and hostname must be lower case
    if (strpos($url, '?')){
      $baseUrl = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, '?'));
      $getParams = substr($url, strpos($url, '?') + 1);
    } else {
     $baseUrl = $url;
     $getParams = "";
    }
    $hostname = strtolower(substr($baseUrl, 0,  strpos($baseUrl, '/', 10)));
    $path = substr($baseUrl, strpos($baseUrl, '/', 10));
    $baseUrl = $hostname . $path;
    $baseString .= rawurlencode($baseUrl) .'&';
    
    //all oauth and get params. First they are decoded, next sorted in alphabetical order, next each key and values is encoded and finally whole parameters are encoded
    $params = array();
    $params['oauth_consumer_key'] = array($consumerKey);
    $params['oauth_token'] = array($tokenKey);
    $params['oauth_nonce'] = array($nonce);
    $params['oauth_timestamp'] = array($timestamp);
    $params['oauth_signature_method'] = array($signatureMethod);
    $params['oauth_version'] = array($version);
     
    foreach (explode('&', $getParams ."&". $postParams) as $param) {
      $parsed = explode('=', $param);
      if ($parsed[0] != "") {
        $value = isset($parsed[1]) ? urldecode($parsed[1]): "";
        if (isset($params[urldecode($parsed[0])])) {
          array_push($params[urldecode($parsed[0])], $value);
        } else {
          $params[urldecode($parsed[0])] = array($value);
        }
      }
    }
     
    //all parameters must be sorted in alphabetical order 
    ksort($params);
     
    $paramString = "";
    foreach ($params as $key => $valueArray){
      //all values must sorted in alphabetical order
      sort($valueArray);
      foreach ($valueArray as $value){
        $paramString .= rawurlencode($key) . '='. rawurlencode($value) .'&';
      }
    }
    $paramString = substr($paramString, 0, -1);
    $baseString .= rawurlencode($paramString);
    return $baseString;
}
```

***Example of valid authorization header created by Postman***

```
Authorization: OAuth realm="1234567_SB1"
    ,oauth_consumer_key="8daa8433f54386d63a5317d71fef801cf47a8cc3d9552be3d0f63fc8ab6de8f9"
    ,oauth_token="65d48649dcf0f8ad2da444af1d16377232bb4a5f8ffa8f3fb6175a3e6a8ed0e5"
    ,oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256"
    ,oauth_timestamp="1710773563"
    ,oauth_nonce="qcFwZvbnJ5u"
    ,oauth_version="1.0"
    ,oauth_signature="iL7L430GE%2Bdw5oSBISr848VKNFm5LLsMskiMD362qCk%3D"
```

***Example of invalid authorization header created by PHP***

```
Authorization: OAuth realm="1234567_SB1"
    ,oauth_consumer_key="8daa8433f54386d63a5317d71fef801cf47a8cc3d9552be3d0f63fc8ab6de8f9"
    ,oauth_token="65d48649dcf0f8ad2da444af1d16377232bb4a5f8ffa8f3fb6175a3e6a8ed0e5"
    ,oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256"
    ,oauth_timestamp="1710775464"
    ,oauth_nonce="3Hulo6OPf78"
    ,oauth_version="1.0"
    ,oauth_signature="zQlMYe%2F9VtANAvgvJo%2Bs7SvLMTvcrrJcOa8Yz5wLQsM%3D"
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you as signing enough - I had to do the same in Delphi and got it to work.  Also, the keys to be signed need to be in alphabetical order. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957730/delphi-toauth1authenticator-how-to-set-the-realm

Comment: @Brian Thank you for this. This requirement seems to be devoid of any mention in the official documentation. I found and tried they're provided function for creating the base string, which includes alphabetizing the signed values, but still have no luck.

Comment: Still doesn't look like you are signing enough - where are including `deploy` and `script` for example?

Comment: @brian `deploy` and `script` are first added to the `$url` where it's being set just under all the define calls at the top. Those then get included in the signed string in the `restletBaseString` function in the `if (strpos($url, '?'))` block. I've confirmed in debugging that they are being included in the base string.

Answer (score 0):

The comments provided by @Brian were correct, in that I was not originally signing enough values, and the values I was signing were not alphabetically sorted by their key. Furthermore, when trying to use the `restletBaseString` function provided by NetSuite, I was generating a new nonce and a new timestamp to create the base string, and then still using the nonce and timestamp I created previously in the `$authorizor` array when creating the headers. This caused a mismatch of values between the signature and the headers.